# Graphics drivers for Intel Core i5-1035G4?

Tags: drivers, graphics, display-resolution, brightness

My new [laptop](https://support.hp.com/de-de/document/c06506318) came with Intel Core i5-1035G4 processor. I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.3. It has only one resolution in the display menu and the brightness controls are missing. This is most probably due to the graphics drivers but I can't seem to find graphics drivers for Ubuntu.

Does anyone know how I can update the graphics drivers?

Edit:

`lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a5a (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 86c9
    Kernel modules: i915
```

`uname -a`

```
Linux linux 5.0.0-23-generic #24~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 29 16:12:28 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: There are no installable drivers for Intel adapters. You could ask about brightness control. Some laptops need some tweaking.

Comment: @Pilot6 How about display-resolution? Is there anyway to add more? I have a FHD screen but the resolution is 1024x768 (4:3).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: And also output of `uname -a`

Comment: @Pilot6 Added info as requested.

Comment: First upadte your system by `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and reboot. If it is not fixed, I'll suggest another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this adapter is not supported by the 5.0.0-23 Linux kernel.

First update your system by

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

reboot and test.

If this doesn't help, try the 5.3 kernel that can be installed by

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge
```

reboot to apply.

Comment: Thank you so much. The new kernel fixed the brightness controls and replaced the 1024x768 (4:3) with 1920x1080 (16:9). I added my desired resolution manually with `xrandr`. But the output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` is still the same. `clinfo` returns number of platforms 0.

Comment: The output is not the same, now you have the correct driver in use.

Comment: [This is the output.](https://pastebin.com/kaCU7vxL)

Comment: So that's what I wrote. See the difference?

Comment: The kernel driver line.

Comment: That fixed the issue.